# Recovered Ubuntu, but it still launches corrupt version

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery

I am Ubuntu newbie, so this one may be obvious.

While playing with some Ubuntu themes, I have messed something up with my Ubuntu 14.04 (keyboard stopped working and Unity looks damaged too - no bars etc.), so i used Advanced options in GRUB Menu and picked up one of the previous versions. Recovery was successful.

However, when i restart my laptop, it loads the corrupt version of Ubuntu, where i can't even launch the Terminal.

I can repeat the whole process and recover it again, but is there a way to set the "recovered Ubuntu" as a default one ?

Comment: What makes you think that "Recovery was successful"? Grub lets you select an older kernel version, which has nothing to do with themes or recovering. You should probably provide more info on the theme in question.

Comment: Yes. There are at least two ways to do this that I know of. 1 is by manually removing the offending kernel and updating grub. Another perhaps easier way is to install grub customiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have a problem with a recent kernel version. I have seen this happen before. I think an easy way to resolve this is with grub customizer. First install it. information is here: https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer

When you run it you'll get something similar to this: 
[image: grub customizer]
Simply uncheck the boxes for the kernel that is giving you problems and keep the ones you want to use checked.

Then click Save and Then File and Install to MBR

This should get you through until the next kernel update by which time you may find the problem is resolved.

Comment: I have done it, as you suggested, and in seems to work ! Thank you. I have one more question. Now I use Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-27-generic. Before, it was 13.0-29-generic. Are there any consequences of such change ?

Comment: it should be fine. the next kernel update will change to the most current kernel. It might help to file a bug report on 13.0.29.xx-generic if that's the one you had the issue with. Please upvote my answer if it was helpful so others with the same issue can find it and benefit. Thank you!

Comment: I'd love to, but I need 15+ rep to do so. Thanks once again.